# Modulo question 5

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all integers $x$ such that $6x$ is a multiple of $21$. I'm assuming I have to use mod since that's what we are using in class.
Would it be $6x\equiv$ mod $21$?

Comment: No, $6x$ is a multiple of $21$ can be written $6x \equiv 0 \pmod{21}$.

Comment: so $x\equiv$ 0 mod 21?

Comment: @emathh7; No. $6x \equiv 0 \pmod{21}$ means that there exists an integer $k$ such that $6x = 21k$. Divide by $3$, and you get $2x = 7k$, namely $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal; so then any x that works in that mod would be the answer, like if x=5, 7 etc? Sorry, I just learned mods today so still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

Comment: @emathh7: neither $5$ or $7$ are solutions of the equation $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, because $2\times 5 = 10$ and $10$ is not a multiple of $7$. Same for $7$.

Comment: Oh right right right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like another user has commented, using modulo notation, you would say $6x\equiv 0\pmod{21}$.
This is equivalent to saying $k,x \in \Bbb Z : 6x-0=21k \iff 6x=21k \iff 2x=7k \iff 2x \equiv 0\pmod{7}$

We are looking for solutions of the equation above, which implies $7k$ must be divisible by $2$. $2|7k \implies k=2n, n\in\Bbb Z$, because $2\nmid7$, which means $2|k$.

Thus, $2x=7k=7\times2n \iff x=7n$

Comment: I suggest using \$6x\equiv0\pmod{21}\$ in the Mathjax to get an equation like $6x\equiv0\pmod{21}$ so the spacing etc. is correct, and **mod** is not italicised.

Comment: and using \times for multiplication instead of *.

Comment: @Marconius thanks for that, I don't know much about MathJax notation, I've corrected it!.

Comment: @JonSnow Is it that I know my 2x must be even or/and that k has to be even since 2x is even?

Comment: @JonSnow - that's cool. There's a guide at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1

Comment: @ematth7 We're looking for solutions of the equation that satisfy $2x=7k$, so $7k$ must be divisible by 2. But since 7 is clearly not divisible by 2, $k$ must be divisible by 2, therefore we say $k=2n, n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @JohnSnow: Suppose $14 | 7k$. The fact that $14$ doesn't divide $7$ doesn't imply that $14$ divide $k$.  Once you have $2x\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, you just need to invoke Euclid's lemma (if $a | bc$ and $\textrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ then $a | c$) to conclude that $7 | x$.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal, yes, that is more concise. I did forget to mention that this is only true if $\gcd{(2,7)}=1$, but that should be clear since both $2$ and $7$ are prime.